# editing in SCSS file not working with HTML

Tags: html, css, sass

i downloaded a theme when i am going to edit the background of "navbar_fixed"in     `<header class="main_menu_area navbar_fixed">`     .scss code for custom css then it will not working with html file it always shows the older codes within it

this is a css file which is working with their html file, i tried many times to edit .scss file but it always gonna fail and it always shows their previous codes.

HTML code:

`````
<header class="main_menu_area navbar_fixed">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </button>

            `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown submenu">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="service.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Services
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="bigdata-hadoop.html">BigData Hadoop</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="artifical-inteligance.html">Artifical Inteligance</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="machine-learning.html">Machine Learning</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="embaded-system.html">Embaded System</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="internet-of-things.html">Internet of Things (IOT)</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="soft-skills.html">Soft Skills</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="service.html">Tutorials</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Gallary</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Career</a></li>
                   <!-- <li class="nav-item dropdown submenu">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Blog
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="single-blog.html">Blog Details</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>-->
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>````
`````

.SCSS code

`````
/* Main Menu Area css
============================================================================================ */
    ````.main_menu_area{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 30;
    padding: 0px 45px;
    .navbar{
        padding: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-color: transparent !important;
        .navbar-toggler{
            border: none;
            border-radius: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            span{
                height: 3px;
                width: 25px;
                display: block;
                background: $dip;
                margin-bottom: 3px;
                &:last-child{
                    margin-bottom: 0px;
                }
            }
        }
        .navbar-collapse{
            @media (min-width: 992px){
                text-align: right;
                display: block !important;
            }
        }
        .navbar-nav{
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: right;
            li{
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: 55px;
                a{
                    font-size: 13px;
                    font-family: $rob;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    color: #fff;
                    letter-spacing: .65px;
                    padding: 0px;
                    line-height: 118px;
                    @include transition;
                }
                &:last-child{
                    margin-right: 0px;
                }
                &.submenu{
                    .dropdown-menu{
                        @media(min-width: 992px){
                            transform: scaleY(0);
                            transition: all 400ms ease-out;
                            display: block;
                            transform-origin: 50% 0;
                            min-width: 250px;
                            background: #171717;
                            left: auto;
                            right: 0px;
                            top: 90%;
                            border-radius: 0px;
                            border: none;
                            padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
                            box-shadow: none;
                            visibility: hidden;
                        }
                        li{
                            margin-right: 0px;
                            display: block;
                            a{
                                display: block;
                                line-height: 38px;
                                color: #fff;
                                font-family: $rob;
                                letter-spacing: .48px;
                                font-size: 16px;
                                padding: 0px 30px;
                                text-transform: inherit;
                                @include transition;
                                font-weight: normal;
                                text-shadow: none;
                            }
                            &:hover{
                                a{
                                    color: $baseColor;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                &:hover{
                    @media(min-width: 992px){
                        &.submenu{
                            .dropdown-menu{
                                transform: scaleY(1);
                                visibility: visible;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                &:hover, &.active{
                    a{
                        color: $dip;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    &.navbar_fixed{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: -70px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: $gradient;
        /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6); */
        transform: translateY(70px);
        transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
        -webkit-transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
        z-index: 999999;
        .navbar{
            .navbar-nav{
                li{
                    a{
                        line-height: 70px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}````

/* End Main Menu Area css
============================================================================================ */

`$rob: 'Roboto', sans-serif;`
`$open: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;`
`$baseColor: #97ccfe;`
`$dip: #0b1033;`
`$pfont: #7c8d93;`

`$gradient: linear-gradient(to right, #b1abdb 0%, #a6d6ff 100%);`
`$mrgn:-10px;`
`````

i expect the output of changing the background of fixed navbar after scrolling down.

Comment: You need to use a Live SASS Compiler when working with scss files. HTML doesn't recognise sass, so you first need to compile it to normal css - and put this compiled file into the <link rel> tag in your HTML.

Comment: Do you compile the sass file? ùin your html your css file is positioned after the original css file?

Comment: Run it with https://www.sassmeister.com/ and then copy the 'real' css to your style.css-file. you need to compile your sass file to pure css in order to get the html to understand your styling.

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 yes i tried but its not working. you may check the link http://bitbasket.co.in/Projects

Comment: @Sfili_81 yes i compiled saas but its not working.

Comment: Have you check your sidebar with console browser?

Comment: Two things, Sass !== Saas and why are the vars between ticks?

Answer (score 0):

You have to LIVE compile your sass to generate a `.css` file using your `.scss` program. you can use the koala-app as your live SASS compiler [here](http://koala-app.com/) and then link the generated .css file at your html file with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="the_path_to_your_css_file.css" />` and then it's like linking a normal css file in your project.